Spark emr jobs: Is the number of task defined by AQE (adaptive.enabled)?
I see the number of task in spark job is only 1000 after initial read, where as number of cores available is 9000 (1800 executors*5 core each). I have enabled aqe and coalesce shuffle partition. In the pic below you can see there is only 1000 task runnings. However the input task with 256 mb split is around 141000. The code is in pyspark (sql aggregated function on top of s3 and writing back to s3)
My question:

Is 1000 task defined by spark as part of AQE after shuffle?
If Cluster is going to use 1000 task aka 1000 cores max, is it ideal to reduce the number of executors. [ Note I have 150 r5.16xlarge.64 vCore, 512 GiB memory]


spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=256m \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionSize=256m \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionNum=27000 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=5400s  --conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g \
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.05 --conf spark.memory.fraction=.8 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.completed=0.99 \
--conf spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold=4000000 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=1200s \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1800 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=32g --conf spark.driver.memory=60g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g \



it seems that you have spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 1000.
Can you please check this in Spark UI - Environment tab.

When you enable AQE and coalesce partitions, Spark will attempt to reduce the number of shuffle partitions to a specified size in MB
Spark documentation details:

This feature simplifies the tuning of shuffle partition number when running queries. You do not need to set a proper shuffle partition number to fit your dataset. Spark can pick the proper shuffle partition number at runtime once you set a large enough initial number of shuffle partitions

I have noticed you do not have initialPartitionNum set in your configuration, which is the only variable with no default value set in Spark. You might want to check that out as a next step
Refer to this article to help you understand more about the details of what Spark is doing

I have added that too but see these 1000 task after AQE and that is failing the job with memory error.
